# "FBAPIErrorDomain error 404" when trying to integrate Facebook Messenger into iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-messenger

This happens while trying to integrate the just-released FBSDKMessengerShareKit. From my IOS app I am calling

```
[FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:myImg withOptions:nil];
```

Messenger launches, with my image showing in the top-left. I choose a recipient (who is also set as an "admin" of the app) and I get a popup that says:

> Send Failed
>
> The operation couldn't be completed.
>
> (FBAPIErrorDomain error 404.)

Anyone know how to resolve this, or what I might do to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have solve this issue with adding Bundle Identifier into Facebook App.
Please add Bundle Identifier into Facebook app and make sure you are using the same Bundle Identifier into the app.**

Comment: Thanks, I had entered a Bundle Identifier, but it turned out it was the wrong one. (For legacy reasons we had a few similar but different com.companyname.app identifiers floating around.) Your answer made me double-check.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Just forgot to add FacebookAppID and Url scheme to my app Info.plist. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#configurePlist

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't my particular problem but it clearly could be a solution for some people.